# Switching between test and real url using conditional statement in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to use local urls for testing. How do I switch between test and real url at compile time?

I'm aware of Active Compilation Conditions but I don't want to use that as it's debug/release thing. I want to switch between test and real urls whenever I wish during my development phase and testing. To do so I want to have a flag which I can change before compilation.

Here is what I want to achieve, it's a pseudo code.

```
#define TEST=TRUE (or FALSE)

#if TEST
static let URL = "http://127.0.0.1/api/"
//... other code
#else
static let URL = "https:// domain.com/api/"
//... other code
#endif
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by saying you want to switch URLs. Are you talking at compile time, or while the app is running? If it’s compile time just declare a bool and change it as needed.

Comment: It's compile time. Not sure how it will work with bool? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, then if you want to be able to change URL during development without making a new build, you have different options, but a quick one is always a hidden configuration popup or menu that you access from your first screen before doing login or whatever.

**Where the hidden menu comes out**: is something you want to decide but maybe, somewhere in a starting ViewController, or onboarding or login, you want to add a Gesture Recognizer for example to show your hidden menu, let's say a double tap anywhere in your `ViewController.view` which will present a hidden configuration alert only in a Debug build, and not a release, just before the login or any relevant api call:

```
#if DEBUG
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(presentHiddenConfigurationAlert))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
#endif
```

**How the hidden menu looks like and act like**: now as well in the same ViewController (so as in my example, a LoginVC or whatever you wish) you'd have the selector method on double tap as this one for example to show an alert that can let you change your current url (as always this can happen only in a Debuggable build):

```
#if DEBUG
@objc func presentHiddenConfigurationAlert() {
    let currentURL = UserDefaults.string(forKey: "current_url")

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Hidden Configuration", message: "You are using \(currentURL)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // add a textview to let developer input the url he wants to use as an action

    // or add some actions as buttons to choose between a Test URL button action and Dev URL button action

    // store the URL as of "current_url" so you can retrieve it in an instance used across the app and here in the message

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
#endif
```

And overall the use case is, in my example:

- you install the app and are in a debuggable build
- a login viewcontroller is the first thing that is shown (for example)
- you or another developer using this build double tap anywhere in this viewcontroller
- a hidden menu alert config is shown where you can change the current URL that is used across the app
- you store this URL in user defaults or where you like most
- now wherever you access the URL variable, you want that in debug you use the one from user defaults and in release you use a release one

> ```
> #if DEBUG
> var API_URL = getURLFromUserDefaults()
> #else
> var API_URL = "https://www.release-product-url.com"
> #endif
> ```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify it before. I want to switch between test and real urls whenever I wish during my development phase. I'm already aware of what you have replied.

Comment: @Raymond I updated my answer as your question changed, the implementation of the alert I think you can make it yourself as you wish, I just put some insights there to let you continue as the way you think is better for you or the developers working on the project

Comment: @denis_for sorry it's not what I want. I've updated my question again. I hope it clarifies now.

Comment: @Raymond what you want is to manuallly change the URL as you test the app, and that is only possible through a hidden configuration in a debuggable build. If you want to use an Active Compilation Condition such as #if TEST it is just extra work to make it happen that way, and not sure how possible it is without making a new build. The point is, Active Compilation Condition are mostly useful when in my opinion you want to make a new build through a configuration (DEBUG, RELEASE, TEST...)

Comment: You may be right. I've already got it working via active compilation condition. I just wanted to check if there was any other way to do so.

Comment: @Raymond did it answer your question?